# Understanding resx file in vb.net project

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, resx

When i compare my vb.net project with my previous version i can see some changes in resx file.But i am not able to understand it.I have not added any new resource actually. but still i can see some changes.
I saw [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekyft91f%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) article where i got some basics about it.That is data and value tag incase of any new resource is added.But in my project i can see some changes like below.

**new**

```
 <data name="PicForward.Image" type="System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">
        <value>
 Qk1SDAAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAAIQAAAB8AAAABABgAAAAAAAAAAADEDgAAxA4AAAAAAAAAAAAAxOz4xOz4
        xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4
        xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4EcTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs
        +MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs
        +MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+BHE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE            
    </value>
      </data>
```

**old**

```
    <data name="PicForward.Image" type="System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">
        <value>
Qk1SDAAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAAIQAAAB8AAAABABgAAAAAAAAAAADEDgAAxA4AAAAAAAAAAAAAxOz4xOz4
        xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4
        xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4xOz4EcTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs
        +MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs
        +MTs+MTs+MTs+MTs+ADE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE7PjE            
    </value>
      </data>
```

In above case in between the value tag there was so many characters like this.I have skipped it as it is lengthy. But i cant understand why this value tag changed(only small changes i have observed).I am creating project using visual studio.I am not directly editing anything in resx file.
 So please clear my doubts related to it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this change is because you are working with an image being saved (to the .resx file) as a base 64 string.

see the mimetype -

```
mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64"

<data name="PicForward.Image" type="System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">
```

So when the image gets saved, or changes - the Base64 needs to be re-written to the .resx file, hence, it changes.

Comment: If i don't change the image then also it is modified?But why?

Comment: @ITresearcher Does this happen on each build? (i.e. does the .resx file change everytime you rebuild)?

Comment: I just added some characters(just to test resx file changes or not) to .vb file and its corresponding resx file got changed on saving.